# Translate computed property from Category into Swift Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have the following objective-c category:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (Awesome)
static char overlayKey;
static char emptyImageKey;

- (UIView *)overlay
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &overlayKey);
}

- (void)setOverlay:(UIView *)overlay
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &overlayKey, overlay, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
@end
```

I tried to translate it into a Swift extension like this:

```
var AssociatedObjectHandle: UInt8 = 0

extension UINavigationBar {

 var overlay:UIView! {
    get {
      return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectHandle) as! UIView
    }
    set(newValue) {
      objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectHandle, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
    }

  }

}
```

It looks strange because I created a global variable `AssociatedObjectHandle` and I am not sure what the Character actually does?

**Is this the correct way to translate the computed property?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked: "Is this the correct way to translate the computed property?"

Ermm, no.

What you are doing is not translating a computed property. It looks like you're using associated objects to simulate a stored property in an extension.

If that is your intention (adding a stored property to your UINavigationBar extension) then the code you posted should work.

The `AssociatedObjectHandle` variable is some "magic" that makes associated value storage work. You have to pass in the address of some unique variable that tells the Objective-C runtime what key to use when getting/setting associated values for your class. You simply create a static variable and use it's address in the get/set associated value calls.

Comment: My intension is to translate the category to the equivalent extension

Comment: What you have done should do the same thing as the equivalent Objective-C code.

Comment: Why is the ``static char overlayKey`` inside the category and ``AssociatedObjectHandle`` is a global variable. Isn't there another way to do that?

Comment: @stephan1001: `static char overlayKey;` is defined in the file scope. It does not matter if it is defined inside @implementation or not. I think you achieve the same in Swift with `private var ...`.

Comment: @stephan1001: See http://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/ how to define the object key locally.